# I have the week number of a month, and want to get the first date within that week in PHP

Tags: php, date

Assuming I have the following given information:

```
$year = 2020; 
$month = 7; 

$week_nr_of_month = 2; 

$first_date_in_that_week = ?;
```

I want to know the first date within that week number of month. So in my current situation the output should be the 2020-07-06

How can I calculate this? Thank you.

Comment: What should be the output for $week_nr_of_month=1? 2020-07-01 or 2020-06-29? 2 you said 2020-07-06, that means 3 -> 13th, 4 -> 20th. There is 5 week in month for 2020-07-27?

Comment: Hi - the output for $week_nr_of_month=1 should be 2020-07-01, for 2 it should be 2020-07-06, for 3 it should be  2020-07-13 and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something like this:

```
<?php

function myDate(int $year, int $month, int $week): string {
  $firstDayDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', '1-'.$month.'-'.$year);
  $firstDayDate->setTime(0,0);

  $firstMondayDate = (clone $firstDayDate)->modify('first monday of this month');
  $modificator = $week - 2;

  if ($firstMondayDate->format('d') === $firstDayDate->format('d')) {
    $modificator++;
  }

  if ($modificator < 0) {
    return $firstDayDate->format('Y-m-d');
  }

  $wantedWeekDate = (clone $firstMondayDate)->add(new DateInterval('P'.($modificator*7).'D'));
  
  return $wantedWeekDate->format('Y-m-d');
}

var_dump(
myDate(2020, 7, 1),
myDate(2020, 7, 2),
myDate(2020, 7, 3),
myDate(2020, 7, 4),
myDate(2020, 7, 5),
myDate(2020, 7, 6),

myDate(2020, 8, 1),
myDate(2020, 8, 2),
myDate(2020, 8, 3),
myDate(2020, 8, 4),
myDate(2020, 8, 5),
myDate(2020, 8, 6),

myDate(2014, 12, 1),
myDate(2014, 12, 2),
myDate(2014, 12, 3)
);
```

Tested output:

```
string(10) "2020-07-01"
string(10) "2020-07-06"
string(10) "2020-07-13"
string(10) "2020-07-20"
string(10) "2020-07-27"
string(10) "2020-08-03"

string(10) "2020-08-01"
string(10) "2020-08-03"
string(10) "2020-08-10"
string(10) "2020-08-17"
string(10) "2020-08-24"
string(10) "2020-08-31"

string(10) "2014-12-01"
string(10) "2014-12-08"
string(10) "2014-12-15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function firstDayOfWeekInMonth($year, $month, $week)
{
    $firstOfMonth = strtotime("$year-$month-1");
    $format = 'Y-m-d';
    if ($week == 1) {
        return date($format, $firstOfMonth);
    } else {
        $secondsInOneDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
        $secondInOneWeek = $secondsInOneDay * 7;
        $dayNumberOfFirstOfMonth = date('w', $firstOfMonth); //eg Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, etc.
        $offsetToStartOfWeek = ($dayNumberOfFirstOfMonth - 1) * $secondsInOneDay; // eg Monday is 0 days from Monday, Tuesday is 1 day from Monday etc.
        $startOfWeek1 = $firstOfMonth - $offsetToStartOfWeek; //could be in previous month
        $StartOfWeekN = $startOfWeek1 + ($week - 1) * $secondsInOneWeek; // week-2 is 1-week ahead of week-1's Monday
        return date($format, $StartOfWeekN);
    }
}
```

This algorithm uses the number of seconds since the Unix epoch. This is an integer so all the calculations are done by adding or multiplying integers which should be quite fast. The conversion between a date and an integer only happens once at the start and once at the end of the function.

As an aside, I found finding meaningful names for the start of the week when I was referring to so many different starts of weeks/months quite a challenge.

For comparison I've used the same tests as in blahy's answer:

```
var_dump(
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 7, 1),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 7, 2),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 7, 3),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 7, 4),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 7, 5),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 7, 6),

firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 8, 1),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 8, 2),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 8, 3),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 8, 4),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 8, 5),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2020, 8, 6),

firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2014, 12, 1),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2014, 12, 2),
firstDayOfWeekInMonth(2014, 12, 3)
);
```

```
string(10) "2020-07-01"
string(10) "2020-07-06"
string(10) "2020-07-13"
string(10) "2020-07-20"
string(10) "2020-07-27"
string(10) "2020-08-03"
string(10) "2020-08-01"
string(10) "2020-08-03"
string(10) "2020-08-10"
string(10) "2020-08-17"
string(10) "2020-08-24"
string(10) "2020-08-31"
string(10) "2014-12-01"
string(10) "2014-12-08"
string(10) "2014-12-15"
```